# When using the phrase "two towns over", how many towns are in between the locations in question?

Tags: phrases, expressions

In your opinion, does the phrase "two towns over" imply there being 1 or 2 towns in between your location and the location you're talking about?

Obviously, you could replace "towns" with any kind of location, or change the number of "towns" etc. in between.

Comment: It should be one town more than "one town over".

Comment: @KillingTime Half of an induction argument!

Comment: IMO it means the second town in that direction, so there is one town in between. Similarly "two streets across" means take the second street.

Comment: [the town you're in] [the town next to the town you're in] [the town next to that one] . . . So: one town in between.

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over) gives the relevant sense:

> **over** [postposition] on the other side of {an intervening space, location etc}
>
> - *the next town over*

(POS adjusted [compare *beyond the next town*, where 'beyond' is obviously a preposition] and otherwise slightly adjusted)

So 'two towns over', though it sounds rather unidiomatic, would be 'beyond the next town but one'.

Comment: [*On the left, just about in view is 'The Corner Picture House'. **Two shops along** was the 'Home Made Sweets' shop where hand made sweets were produced in full view of the public.*](https://www.harringayonline.com/photo/wards-corner) I certainly wouldn't stake my life on whether there was ***one*** or ***two*** shops ***in between*** the picture house and the sweet shop.

Comment: That definition doesn't align with my understanding. It suggests _the next town over_ means there is an intervening town, whereas I understand it to mean _the next town_. Also, _two towns over_ sounds perfectly idiomatic to me. https://www.google.com/search?q="two%20towns%20over"&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en "There was Shaun, the kid from two towns over with the bass guitar and Multiple Sclerosis." "Aaron drives to the office, which is two towns over." "Jack had told me that two towns over was the next place we could stay in case the zombies got too close [...]"

Comment: @CJDennis, it absolutely does not suggest an intervening town. What lies between a town and the next is space, or at least a border. Not a town.

Comment: @FF Two shops _along_? The relevance here being?